# Connecting to MSSQL db (PDO, FreeTDS, ODBC)

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, pdo, freetds

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server and I'm trying to establish a connection to a MSSQL database.

I've managed to connect using `tsql` and `isql`, but `osql` doesn't work and connecting with PHP using PDO also isn't working.. I will try to provide as much information as I can and if you need more just let me know and I will edit.

**freetds.conf**:

```
[MSSQL]
  host = TPSACC
  port = 54488
  tds version = 8.0
```

**odbc.ini**:

```
[MSSQL]
Description     = MS SQL connection to PRODUCTION database
Driver          = FreeTDS
Database        = PRODUCTION
Server          = TPSACC
UserName        = sa
Password        = pass
Trace           = No
TDS_Version     = 8.0
Port            = 54488
```

**odbcinst.ini**:

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = ODBC for Microsoft SQL
Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so
UsageCount  = 1
Threading   = 2
```

**~> isql MSSQL sa pass**

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
SQL>
```

**~> tsql -S MSSQL -U 'sa' -P 'pass'**

```
locale is "en_US.UTF-8"
locale charset is "UTF-8"
using default charset "UTF-8"
1>
```

**~> osql -S MSSQL -U sa -P pass**

```
checking shared odbc libraries linked to isql for default directories...
strings: '': No such file
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /etc ... OK
checking odbc.ini files
    reading /home/toolplas/.odbc.ini
[MSSQL] not found in /home/toolplas/.odbc.ini
    reading /etc/odbc.ini
[MSSQL] found in /etc/odbc.ini
found this section:
    [MSSQL]
    Description     = MS SQL connection to PRODUCTION database
    Driver          = FreeTDS
    Database        = PRODUCTION
    Server          = TPSACC
    UserName        = sa
    Password        = pass
    Trace           = No
    TDS_Version     = 8.0
    Port            = 54488
looking for driver for DSN [MSSQL] in /etc/odbc.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver          = FreeTDS"
  driver "FreeTDS" found for [MSSQL] in odbc.ini
found driver named "FreeTDS"
"FreeTDS" is not an executable file
looking for entry named [FreeTDS] in /etc/odbcinst.ini
  found driver line: "  Driver      = /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so"
  found driver /usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so for [FreeTDS] in odbcinst.ini
/usr/local/lib/libtdsodbc.so is an executable file
"Server" found, not using freetds.conf
Server is "TPSACC"
osql: no IP address found for "TPSACC"
```

In PHP I have:

```
$conn = new PDO ("dblib:host=TPSACC;dbname=PRODUCTION","$username","$pw");
```

..or..

```
$conn = new PDO ("dblib:host=TPSACC;port=54488;dbname=PRODUCTION","$username","$pw");
```

And they both return this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

I have been stuck here for a couple days and can't quite figure out why only half of the connections actually work..

Any and all help is really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You're not using ODBC, with those connect strings. You're telling PHP to use the SQL Server-specific DBLIB connector, originally developed as Sybase (hence "Adaptive Server"). You may benefit from reviewing some [documentation on PHP + ODBC](http://www.iodbc.org/dataspace/iodbc/wiki/iODBC/IODBCPHPHOWTO). If you're targeting a recent SQL Server, you may also need a different ODBC driver, as FreeTDS doesn't yet fully support all the new features of SQL Server 2008 and later. [My employer makes a few](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-sqlserver/) you can test for free.

Answer (score 5):

PHP modules installed?

Create a `info.php` file in your webserver (apache2 dir: `/var/www/html` in Ubuntu) with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` for view details. Use `odbcinst -j` for get config files loaded by unixODBC and `tsql -C` for get FreeTDS details; check if  is `MS db-lib source compatibility: yes`.

If the `MS db-lib` is 'no' you need configure freetds with the `--enable-msdblib`.

My `./configure` line:

`./configure --with-tdsver=8.0 --with-unixodbc=/usr/local --enable-msdblib`

Then `sudo make && sudo make install`

This is my working config:

**Freetds.conf:**

```
[MSSQL]
host = 192.168.1.200
port = 1433
tds version = 8.0
client charset = UTF-8
```

**odbc.ini:**

```
[mssql]
Description = MSSQL Server
Driver      = freetds #The odbcinst.ini driver name
ServerName  = MSSQL # The Freetds.conf connection name
Database    = database
TDS_Version = 8.0
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[freetds]
Description = MS SQL database access with Free TDS
Driver      = /usr/lib/libtdsodbc.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbclibtdsS.so
UsageCount  = 1
```

Comment: More detailed: https://www.ettiennelouw.co.za/2016/12/21/mssql-ubuntu-16-php-7-freetds/

In my case works with:

    MS db-lib source compatibility: no